# Html select options appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the below code to convert the blockquote to the options of select element. 
[image]

Please help to make it right as each option. Thank you.

> ["Yes ↵No", "one ↵two ↵three ↵four", "person 1 ↵person 2"]

```
var newArr = [];        
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var data = arr[i].split('\r\n');
            newArr.push(data);    
        }

for (var j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
            $('#metadata-field').append('<select name=""></select>');
            if (newArr[j].length) {
                for (var k = 0; k < newArr[j].length; k++) {
                    $('#metadata-field select').append('<option>' + newArr[j][k] + '</option>');
                }
            } else {
                alert('No data');
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code, what do you mean by "right as each option" ?

Comment: In the attachment you can an array. I want to make select and option by each array index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You need to split array element using `↵` and then append each element using one loop only and not nested loop. See below code -

```js
var arr = ["Yes ↵No", "one ↵two ↵three ↵four", "person 1 ↵person 2"]
    
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var data = arr[i].split(' ↵');
     //create select box
     var $select = $('<select id="' + i + '"></select>');
     $('#metadata-field').append($select);
     for(var k=0;k<data.length;k++)
      {
        //append options in select box
        $select.append('<option>' + data[k] + '</option>');
      }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="metadata-field"></div>
```

Comment: I want to make select items with each array index.

Comment: do you want yes, no in one select box and one, two, three, four in another select box and so on , right?

Comment: happy to help you :)